# Way for floating box but with html code after main block?

Tags: html, css

I have standard `float: left` code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-box" style="float: left"></div>
  <div class="main-div"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is that I have too many html code in `float-box` so I want it to be after `main-div`, but then `float-box` is below `main-div`

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-div"></div>
  <div class="float-box" style="float: left"></div> <!-- below -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to do it in css? 
I don't want to have two columns. `float-box` should take only necessery space - not height of `main-div`

[image]

Comment: Did you try `flex ` to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many HTML code"? I couldn't understand your problem.

Comment: Where and how do you exactly want your blue float box to be?

Comment: You can use absolute positioning

Comment: My purpose is SEO. In yellow box I have main text, in blue box I have usefull links, but with lots of html code (img, stars, text). Blue box should be where it is but blue box's html code should be after yellow box's. `flex` does columns which I don't want.

Comment: does the float element have a fixed width/height?

Comment: No, float-div does not have fixed height

Comment: The contents of the blue box are irrelevant to the position it has in your HTML...just put it before the yellow box in the DOM. If you have your attributes set properly SEO won't be an issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D what do You mean by `attributes`?